# how can I map information form panda data frame column to some visualization?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-visualization

how can I map information from my panda data frame (actually my name entity recognition form the text ) to some beautiful visualization? as you see the table is some observational sentenctes from Mars,  For instance, imagine I want to use the column Entities and visualize entities

DATE, TIME

[image]

do you have any idea?
I saw for instance I can visualize the coordinate using the bokeh, but how can I
visualize   DATA and TIME from the column  Entities for each row
thank you for your time

I have access to this column by

[image]

but I do not know how to process this?

Comment: I could think of displaCy as a nice tool to visualise NER entities. See https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have used spacy for NER visualization, but my question is different, I want to extract from my NER some numerical information and then visualize that ...Imagine entity :date and time, I want to map them to some visualisation ..
do you know what I mean?

Comment: No, I don't know what visualisation you mean. *Some* visualisation is just too broad to give you any help.

Comment: I mean using the TIME entity (e.g. 2h 5m), I could map them to 2D visualisation of  (X=h,Y=m)  for each row that shows them  when the observation happens

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what data you want to visualize:  Do you want to make a [word cloud](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/word-cloud-from-a-pandas-data-frame/) from the long, not-really-readable strings that are currently in Entities? That would technically let you visualize DATE and TIME, but not in a useful way.

First step is probably to normalize the dataframe: You've got a list of attributes mixed into each element in the Entities column. Each list needs to be turned into multiple columns. If you can clean up the data before it gets into a dataframe, that's probably the best bet. Otherwise, you'll probably need to write a custom function and use something like [applymap()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) to convert what's there into a more familiar / standardized format. After that. Additional uses of apply() or applymap() can also be used to produce one column per attribute, assuming some / all of the attributes are meaningful and common.

After that, it again depends heavily on how you want the DATE and TIME to appear. [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) has a bunch of options, and that link will let you skim through them.

Comment: thank you for your response,  i do not want to make word cloud, 
first I want to extract this DATA and TIME, in Way that is comparable!  Then I want to map them to some visualization. ..i did not get how can I use applymap()... bit plotly looks a relvant for later use of visulaization

Comment: The function that you write for use with applymap() is going to depend on the details of how Entities is formed. That will probably involve looping over the elements of the list, looking for the DATE and TIME subfields, then passing the first element of each tuple to datetime.strptime(). If the Entities elements are Strings rather than Lists, you'll need to parse the string with json.loads(), but there are many unknowns in your data format, so it's hard to give a single unambiguous answer